# Laravel 5 Intervention Image 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: image, laravel-5, memory-limit, intervention

In my project, I am able to use intervention to fit the image to certain size, but sometimes when I load the page, some image will become broken image with the error 500. When i refresh again, the image is fine. I have done some research online, and some said that it might be the memory_limit problem, so I already set my memory_limit to 128M but the problem still exist. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Check your server logs first.

Comment: i think i solve it already by using image cache

Comment: @JK9 can you answer your question, I'm face this problem too. thanks.

Comment: @DarkCyber it's actually the memory_limit problem, just set it to a higher value. Did you try to change the value?

Comment: Nah, I don't know where to go? I use Laravel 5.4 on Shared hosting. Where should I increase memory limit?, anyway sometimes when image doesn't loaded I check the response and it says 500 internal server error.

Comment: @DarkCyber Do you have cpanel access to the shared hosting?

Comment: @JK9 yes of course